# crypt password get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in

Tags: php, crypt

i developed mvc with php and mysql and pdo in hosting the site appeared this problem in the admin control panel i created its in the login controller

the problem is as shown in browser

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/trustlabseg/public_html/test/app/C_LoginController.php on line 21

i searched for all the same error in here and its not like that no one solve my problem

the code is

```
  $password = crypt($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 12]);

    $rules = [
                    "username" => "checkReguired|checkStrings",
                    "password" => "checkReguired"
     ];
```

when i delete the last line the page load but still canot loging
please little help here
and thanks alot

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array()` for older PHP versions. Additionally, it is spelled "required" (as in to require).

```
$password = crypt($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 12));
$rules = array("username" => "checkRequired|checkStrings", "password" => "checkRequired");
```

Comment: its little worked but give another error with 'cost' => 12 and i deleted it to page work